# while downloading react app files and folders getting deleted automatically

Tags: reactjs

waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~/myPhoneCourses/codevolution/practiceCode$ npm init react-app my-apps

Creating a new React app in /home/waseem/myPhoneCourses/codevolution/practiceCode/my-apps.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....1.0","@babel/preset-'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/waseem/.npm/_logs/2020-02-15T12_00_11_612Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-apps/ from /home/waseem/myPhoneCourses/codevolution/practiceCode
Done.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` utility or setting project your-self?

Comment: yes i tried that too but i am getting the same result